# Is cloud code sessionToken change in parse server 2.4.x?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I just updated parse-server from 2.2.x to 2.4.x and my cloud code using sessionToken did not work. Below is simple cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('find_device', function(request, response) {
  var user = request.user;
  if(user){
    var token = user.getSessionToken();
    console.log("User token " + token);
    var query = new Parse.Query('devices');
    query.equalTo('deviceId', "389125651274465");
    query.find({ sessionToken: token })//<- sessionToken does not work
    .then(function(messages) {
      response.success(messages);
    },function(error){
      console.log(error);
      response.error("error");
    });
  }else{
    response.error("error");
  }
});
```

It uses `{sessionToken: token}` to query. This code worked before, but now it does not work in parse-server 2.4.x. I received error

```
ParseError { code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }
```

I don't know if anything change in parse-server version 2.4.x. If i change to `{useMasterKey:true}` it works ok, but in this case i want to use user's token to query. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

They havent really changes the the `... query.find({sessionToken : token}) ...` part, but maybe they have changed how `User.getSessionToken()` works.

The [documentations](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_getSessionToken) says :

> String getSessionToken( )
>
> Returns the session token for this user, if
>   the user has been logged in, or if it is the result of a query with
>   the master key. Otherwise, returns undefined.
>
> Returns:  the session token, or undefined

Since in case of cloud-code, neither the user is logged in, not its the result of a query using masterKey, `getSessionToken()` should actually behave that way only.

To correct this, what I would suggest is, rather than making the query on-behalf of the user in the cloud-code(and thus on the server), just let the user make it from the client.

Comment: i did console.log("User token " + token); to see value of token, and token is valid.

Comment: maybe some problem with the class ACL or CLP ? btw, that error code= undefined is a bit awkward

Comment: Document in this collection will be saved with ACL, so user only read and write their own data. If i use rest api with X-Parse-Session-Token direct to this class, Get request works ok.